# Choose the right IMU for our Robot

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are doing a project about controlling the robot using slam to build a real-time map of a building and then ask robot to go to destinations all by itself based on the map. We are going to use ROS real-time operating system, but the realtime map was not that clear,having a lot of noise. So we feel we can use slam with IMU to do the localization and filter better. But since we are requested to use ROS operating system, we tried to find IMU supported by ROS drivers on this link    http://www.ros.org/wiki/Sensors, the problem is the active links on this website leads us to some really expensive IMU sensors like microstrain_3dmgx2_imu(,http://www.ros.org/wiki/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu )at 1700 dollars, otherwise they don't have a link anymore.And we have also checked CH Robotics UM6 IMU,whose price is much more acceptable, but this one has a blank link ,http://www.ros.org/wiki/imu_um6,so we are not sure it has ROS drivers, And we did not found evidence online saying that it support ROS operating system either.

And our concerns also involve that what IMU has the enouth accuracy with the Lidia sensor hokuyo we are using,whether the data rate is compatible with our system and whether it will work well with the robot(Roomba) we are going to use.

Any advice on what kind of IMU should we use? Thanks for any answers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47349/choose-the-right-imu-for-our-robot/) by [marunyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3517/marunyu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a roomba like robot, you might not need a full IMU. A single axis gyro should be sufficient. There are a lot around, but the one used on the turtlebot should have a ROS driver:

http://turtlebot.com/build/create.html

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a link to the Phidgets PhidgetsSpatial 3/3/3 right on the Sensors page you've linked to! It's cheap and works well.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1